CIFS mount: Permissions and Ownership Changes
I have a CIFS mount for an application data. As part of the setup process, the application needs to be able to change the permissions and ownership of the folders within the mount.
I currently have the CIFS share mounted as noperm to avoid any r/w issues on the share. However, on the filesystem, it seems to inherit the ownership on the filesystem root:root and won't be receptive to any ownership changes. Therefore, since it isn't handling ownership change, the application errors out.
Is there any way to "emulate" permissions on the CIFS share? Alternatively, I can move to NFS or iSCSI if it really comes to it.
